# How to ensure that my docker image / container will still work 100 years from now?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have created my Docker compose and Dockerfile but as you can see I am downloading PHP from Docker Hub and also downloading and installing PHP extensions. But what if after 20 years those images / packages will no longer be hosted on Docker hub? What if I want to still be able to run my container then?

Can I somehow freeze my containers in time? Can I bundle it all together so that if I come back to it 100 years from now and run my image it will still work? I don't want it to go out and download anything from the internet. I want to download everything now and just run it in the future.

**Docker compose file**:

```
version: '3'
services:

  php:
    build:
      context: ./php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: php
```

**And my PHP Dockerfile**:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes. When you build a docker image it stores locally on your host machine. As your image already includes everything you need.
You can store it in private docker [registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) and it will work even after 100 years

Comment: So when I run ````docker build```` it will download everything and later when I run the image then it will not have to download anything anymore?

Comment: Yes. Everything described in `Dockerfile` becomes persistent in the final docker image

Comment: Ok, so just be be clear. If I build my image today successfully and come back after 100 years when internet doesn't exist anymore. Then I will still be able to run my image but I won't be able to build it anew?

Comment: Also, just to clarify, is everything persisted in the ````image```` or ````container````?

Comment: everything persisted in `image`. `container` is just an instance of your running image. You can save the container's state but it is more problematic

Answer (score 0):

### You'll need to provide them yourself

If not available in the future you will need to get and save them now by either:

- Creating images that have download the packages now and saved them locally.
- Download the packages now and set up a local server to serve them up as needed in the future.

Comment: How to create images that have all the packages?